# Opening QFile fails when path is dynamically generated

Tags: c++, qt, path, qstring, qfile

Im currently working on a project in QT Designer and I'm totally confused when it comes to file paths.
Im using a QString to save my directory/file path,

`QString filePath;`

fill it with a QFileDialog and then I generate the filename in a stringstream, convert that into QString and add the two togehter.

```
std::stringstream name;

    name  << "/" << now->tm_mday   << now->tm_mon  << now->tm_year + 1900;
    name << now->tm_hour  << now->tm_min << "rec" << ".csv" << std::endl;

QString fName = name.str().c_str();
filePath = filePath + fName;
```

But when I try to open a QFile with it like this, the programm crashes.

`out = new QFile(pathQ);`

The weird thing is, when I print the path to the console and copy paste and hardcode that into filePath it works perfectly fine.

```
std::cout << filePath << std::endl;
```

and
`filePath = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Recordings/6120211616rec.csv"`

It also works when I just hardcode the "/6120211616rec.csv" and add it to filePath.
Does it make any sense that there is a difference in the path, even if it looks the same if printed to the console?

Thanks for your much needed help :)

Comment: I imagine filePath and pathQ are the same thing, right? Could you make a small main to replicate the issue?

Comment: Appending std::endl at the end of name makes out->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) fail. Try withouth it

Comment: That sounds logical. And that explains why hardcoding the string works. I'll try that later when I get home

Comment: For what it's worth, when I have weird issues like this, the first thing I do is print the entire string I'm opening and make sure it makes sense.